# Pull github latest code using Python

Tags: python, github

How Can I pull all the branches available under Master branch using Python command prompt (Implemented the os module for executing the Command)

As of now I am pulling using below command

```
import os
os.system(git pull https://username:password@github.com/Organizationname/reponame.git/)
```

Comment: Have you looked at using https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) which is a python library used to interact with Git repositories?